# I am having trouble using Eigen translate() and rotate() and doesn't behave as expected

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation, transform, eigen

I am trying to find transformation matrices between different coordinate frames. In order to rotate, we basically multiply the rotation matrices and append the translation vector to obtain the final homogeneous matrix.

Here I have attached a snippet of my code where `tf_matrix` and  `output` are `Eigen::Transform` variables.

```
tf_matrix.setIdentity();
tf_matrix.rotate( output.rotation() );
tf_matrix.translate( output.translation() );
```

When I look at their outputs, it seems like it is generating the rotation and translation matrix into 4x4 matrices and multiplying it instead of appending the translation vector

**Output:**

```
//This is rotation matrix
output.rotation()
        1         0         0
        0    0.0707372    -0.997495
        0    0.997495    0.0707372

//translation vector
output.translation()
0.3
0.3
0.3

//After applying rotate() and translate() tf_matrix.transform.matrix() looks like the below
        1         0         0       0.3
        0 0.0707372 -0.997495 -0.278027
        0  0.997495 0.0707372   0.32047
        0         0         0         1


//Printing just the tf_matrix.transform.rotation()
        1         0         0
        0 0.0707372 -0.997495
        0  0.997495 0.0707372


//Printing just the tf_matrix.transform.translation()
      0.3
-0.278027
  0.32047

//Ideally it should look like the below
        1         0         0       0.3
        0 0.0707372 -0.997495       0.3
        0  0.997495 0.0707372       0.3
        0         0         0         1
```

**What did I try**

- I tried to generate a simple 4x4 identity Eigen::Trnasform and append it to the output matrix after the rotation, but the value 1 of the identity matrix gets added
- I also tried, multiply tf_matrix.col(3) += output_matrix.col(3) , but it faces similar issues as above.

I am not sure how to go about rotation because my understanding is that I need to just multiply the 3x3 rotation matrix and append/add the 3x3 translation vector to the final column of this matrix. It seems like Eigen should be able to handle this without me writing extra code. But, this rotate, translate clearly doesn't give the right answers.

Could you please point out what am I missing if any or if there's a better way to go about it.

Comment: Did you try `pretranslate()` instead of `translate()`? If you still have problems, please provide a [mre]!

Answer (score 0):

The order of operations is reversed from what you seem to expect: [see here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Transform.html). Suppose you have a coordinate in R3 that you want to translate (matrix Mt) and then rotate (matrix Mr), you might expect to write `Vec3 = Vec3 * Mt * Mr`. Many game-engines and math libraries (eg Ogre, XNA, CRYENGINE, Unity, I believe) use this order of operations. However, Eigen requires `Vec3 = Mr * Mt * Vec3`; in Eigen, the coordinate being passed through is a column vector, in game engines, it is a row vector. Correspondingly, the matrices in the two different forms are transposes of one another.

To solve you problem:

```
tf_matrix.setIdentity();
tf_matrix = output.rotation() * tf_matrix;
tf_matrix = translate * tf_matrix;
```

or

```
tf_matrix = translate * output.rotation();
```

The `pretranslate()` and `premultiply()` methods can also be used to do this.